# How to match this {% url something

Tags: regex, django

I have many entries in old Django project like this:

```
{% url something param param %}
{% url someother param %}
{% url something %}
```

And I want to user regex to replace it with:

```
{% url "something" param param %}
{% url "someother" param %}
{% url "something" %}
```

I use KomodoEdit and it allows to replace text in many files with using regex. How build regex to match and replace in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `\{% url ([a-z]+)` by `{% url "$1"`.

Answer (score 0):

For Komodo Edit correct answer is:

match:

```
{% url (\S*)
```

with space on end, and replace:

```
{% url "\1"
```

with space on end